# Update hidden attribute in LoopbackJS

Tags: postgresql, loopbackjs, instance-methods

I have a strange problem in LoopbackJS. In one of my persisted models which are saved in PostgreSQL, I am not able to change the value of some fields of an instance with **.save()** or **.updateAttributes** methods.

Another thing, these fields are hidden so I can't use remote methods to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, by logging the loopback process, it was produced by an observer function which another developer added to the project!

Comment: is it a clarification for the question or an answer?

Comment: @tashakori It's the answer of my problem.

Comment: Good, i thought that you needed a hand in modifying those attributes by utilizing the observer functions.